# Visual studio enterprise 2017 targeting

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

When I am creating a project I am missing the targeting framework selection. This is how my installer looks

[image]

But still can't select the target framework. Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

This is expected, it will sort of default you to latest to help you stay current. After creation, you can go into the properties to switch the target framework type. Depending on the type of framework you'd want to use, it is important to select from the "Windows Classic Desktop" and the "Web Previous Versions" project categories, the different flavors of .NET 3 and 4 are only available through these project categories, when you select one of these project types you should also see the Framework Version selector at the bottom of the Creation window:

[image]

For the .NET Standard and .NET Core you switch them after creation.

Comment: The issue is that I am creating an Episerver project and it tries to target 4.5.1 while it shoul try and target 4.6.1. So it doesn't create the project for me. Even if I go and change the target framework later on it doesn't work.

Comment: That may be an issue with the EpiServer project template and worth a different more specific question.